# Locking and Skipping Locked Rows in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, mariadb, typeorm

In the database, there are 2 rows that match the query condition. If we run two parallel queries, the first query locks both rows and returns one, while the second query returns `null`.

It would be desirable to have the ability to lock only one (returned) row to avoid such a situation.

```
const queryRunner : QueryRunner = this.connect.createQueryRunner();
await queryRunner.connect();
await queryRunner.startTransaction();
const identificationProcess = await queryRunner.manager
            .getRepository(IdentificationProcessEntity)
            .createQueryBuilder("identification_process")
            .orderBy("identification_process.updated_at", "ASC")
            .where("identification_process.status = :status", { status: IdentificationStatusEnum.Scanning })
            .useTransaction(true)
            .setLock("pessimistic_write")
            .setOnLocked("skip_locked")
            .take(1)
            .getOne()
```

I have tried changing the query parameters.

MariaDB - v10.8.4

SQL:

```
query: SELECT `identification_process`.`uid` AS `identification_process_uid`, `identification_process`.`user_uid` AS `identification
_process_user_uid`, `identification_process`.`status` AS `identification_process_status`, `identification_process`.`attempts` AS `id
entification_process_attempts`, `identification_process`.`expire_at` AS `identification_process_expire_at`, `identification_process`
.`created_at` AS `identification_process_created_at`, `identification_process`.`updated_at` AS `identification_process_updated_at`, 
`identification_process`.`procedure_uid` AS `identification_process_procedure_uid` FROM `identification_process` `identification_pro
cess` WHERE `identification_process`.`status` = ? ORDER BY `identification_process`.`updated_at` ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED 
-- PARAMETERS: ["Scanning"]
```

Comment: Which MariaDB version? (10.6+ required) - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/#skip-locked. Can you show the SQL query JS is doing? A "limit 1" might be better as that's pushed down.

Comment: Supplemented the question

Comment: The locks are always on indexes. I suspect you haven't got a combined index for `status,updated_at`? or its not being used in the query `explain {query}`?

Comment: Thank you, adding an index for the status field helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locks are always on indexes. So to ensure the minimal amount of locks are obtained for the query, the query needs to use an index in the optimal way for the least locks to be created.

While indexing is a [big and important topic](https://use-the-index-luke.com/), that is highly recommended in support of optimal queries (and energy conservation), lets look at the query in the question.

There is a simple one table lookup, no joins, so look at the `where` criteria. Searching on `status` requires an index on status. After this is found, the results are sorted by `updated_at`. This forms the second part of the compound index.

As such the index in SQL is created with:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_status_updated_at ON identification_process (status, updated_at)
```

Or going by the [TypeORM docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/indices#indices-with-multiple-columns):

```
@Entity()
...
@Index(["status", "updated_at"])
...
export class identification_process {
```

Comment: Indexes really helped, thank you!
But I have encountered another similar issue, when using TypeORM with `relations: { subscribers: true }` in the query and SQL with `LEFT JOIN`, the query still locks all the rows that match the condition despite the LIMIT 1.

Comment: Hmm. Depends on the query, ask a new question. `EXPLAIN {query}` shows what indexes are used and how the query was executed.

Comment: A new question about this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77221510/block-and-skip-locked-rows-with-left-join-in-mariadb