# Block and skip locked rows with LEFT JOIN in MariaDB

Tags: node.js, transactions, mariadb, typeorm

There are 3 tables in the database: 1 - `push_mailings`, 2 - `push_subscriptions`, 3 - `push_mailings_and_subscriptions_relations` (Many-to-Many relationship between push_mailings and push_subscriptions).
I am using MariaDB and TypeORM.

```
const queryRunner = await this.connection.createQueryRunner();
await queryRunner.connect();
await queryRunner.startTransaction('READ COMMITTED');
pushMailing = await queryRunner.manager.findOne(PushMailingEntity, {
        where: {
          status: Equal(MailingStatusEnum.WaitingStart),
          date_send: LessThanOrEqual(dateNow)
        },
        order: {
          date_send: 'DESC'
        },
        relations: {
          subscribers: true
        },
        lock: {
          mode: 'pessimistic_write',
          onLocked: 'skip_locked',
        },
        transaction: true
      });
```

From this code, I expect to retrieve 1 record that satisfies the condition and simultaneously lock it for other queries.
I do retrieve 1 record, but **all** records that satisfy the condition are being locked.
If relations: {subscribers: true} is not used, then the blocking occurs only on one record, as I need.
What could be the possible error in my code?

SQL

```
 SELECT DISTINCT `distinctAlias`.`PushMailingEntity_uid` AS `ids_PushMailingEntity_uid`, `distinctAlias`.`PushMailingEntity_date_send` FROM (SELECT `PushMailingEntity`.`uid` AS `PushMailingEntity_uid`, `PushMailingEntity`.`name_campaign` AS `PushMailingEntity_name_campaign`, `PushMailingEntity`.`status` AS `PushMailingEntity_status`, `PushMailingEntity`.`count_subscribers` AS `PushMailingEntity_count_subscribers`, `PushMailingEntity`.`failed_send` AS `PushMailingEntity_failed_send`, `PushMailingEntity`.`click` AS `PushMailingEntity_click`, `PushMailingEntity`.`close` AS `PushMailingEntity_close`, `PushMailingEntity`.`date_send` AS `PushMailingEntity_date_send`, `PushMailingEntity`.`date_analytics` AS `PushMailingEntity_date_analytics`, `PushMailingEntity`.`message` AS `PushMailingEntity_message`, `PushMailingEntity`.`created_at` AS `PushMailingEntity_created_at`, `PushMailingEntity`.`updated_at` AS `PushMailingEntity_updated_at`, `PushMailingEntity`.`deleted_at` AS `PushMailingEntity_deleted_at`, `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers`.`uid` AS `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers_uid`, `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers`.`user_uid` AS `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers_user_uid`, `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers`.`subscriber_id` AS `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers_subscriber_id`, `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers`.`is_active` AS `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers_is_active`, `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers`.`created_at` AS `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers_created_at`, `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers`.`updated_at` AS `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers_updated_at`, `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers`.`deleted_at` AS `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers_deleted_at` FROM `push_mailings` `PushMailingEntity` LEFT JOIN `push_mailings_and_subscriptions_relations` `9c3ea7c22ae3a7b96cf1006255a47a86e1441af0` ON `9c3ea7c22ae3a7b96cf1006255a47a86e1441af0`.`push_mailing_uid`=`PushMailingEntity`.`uid` LEFT JOIN `push_subscriptions` `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers` ON `PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers`.`uid`=`9c3ea7c22ae3a7b96cf1006255a47a86e1441af0`.`push_subscription_uid` AND (`PushMailingEntity__PushMailingEntity_subscribers`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) WHERE ( (`PushMailingEntity`.`status` = "WaitingStart" AND `PushMailingEntity`.`date_send` <= "2023-10-03T09:50:30.031Z") ) AND ( `PushMailingEntity`.`deleted_at` IS NULL ) FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) `distinctAlias` ORDER BY `distinctAlias`.`PushMailingEntity_date_send` DESC, `PushMailingEntity_uid` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Tried various versions of the query.